# Why does the function t return a t.test for objects with class set to "test"?

Tags: r

I'm reading Hadley Wickham's book Advanced R, specifically the OO fied guide (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html). The first exercise in that chapter is as follows:

*Read the source code for t() and t.test() and confirm that t.test() is an S3 generic and not an S3 method. What happens if you create an object with class test and call t() with it?*

If I understood the chapter correctly, we can confirm that t() and t.test() are generic, because they use the UseMethod() function in the source code. methods(t) returns t.data.frame, t.default and t.ts* as the methods of function t(). Why then, if both are S3 generics and t does not have a t.test method, does the following code return the t test?

```
a <- structure(1:4, class = "test")
t(a)
```

My prediction would be that t would use the default method for class "test" and  t.default(a) does the transpose as logically I suppose it should. Where then does the t.test come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `t(a)`, where `a` is your object of class `test`, then  `UseMethod("t")` is called. This will check what the class of the first argument that you provided to `t()` is. The class is `test` and R will now
 look for a function `t.test()`. Since `t.test()` exists, `t.test(a)` is run. This is called "method dispatch".

Only if `t.test()` did not exist, R would resort to calling `t.default()`. You can actually even see this happen, by detaching the `stats` package before running `t(a)`:

```
a <- structure(1:4, class = "test")
detach("package:stats")
t(a)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "test"
```

The question is now, why `t.test` is not contained in the list, when you run `methods("t")`. When you look at the source code of `methods()`, you will notice that it calls `.S3methods()`. This function compiles the names of all the methods of `t`. However, at some point, it removes the function names that are contained in `S3MethodsStopList`:

```
info <- info[grep(name, row.names(info)), ]
info <- info[!row.names(info) %in% S3MethodsStopList, 
    ]
```

(If I run edit(.S3methods) in RStudio, these are lines 47 and 48).

`S3MethodsStopList` is defined earlier (on line 15):

```
S3MethodsStopList <- tools:::.make_S3_methods_stop_list(NULL)
```

The function `tools:::.make_S3_methods_stop_list()` seems not to be documented, but it just seems to return a hardcoded list of function names that contain a dot, but are actually not methods. `t.test()` is one of them:

```
grep("^t\\.", tools:::.make_S3_methods_stop_list(NULL), value = TRUE)
##                 Hmisc6             calibrator                 mosaic               mratios1 
##       "t.test.cluster"                "t.fun"               "t.test"        "t.test.ration" 
##               mratios2               mratios3                 stats6 
## "t.test.ratio.default" "t.test.ratio.formula"
```

In short, `methods()` does explicitly filter out functions that are known not to be methods. Method dispatching, on the other hand, simply looks for a function with an appropriate name.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the thorough explanation!